# Однородность обстоятельств

Tags: пунктуация

Являются ли однородными обстоятельства "из уст в уста" и "из года в год"? С одной стороны, нет, потому что они принадлежат разным видам. С другой – в предложении будто бы происходит ассимиляция: хочется поставить запятую, ввиду того что создаётся видимость однородности.

*Как не изменить того, что передавалось из года в год (?) из уст в уста?*

Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Давайте порассуждаем.

*Как не изменить того, что передавалось из года в год из уст в уста?*

Из года в год - это  обстоят. времени: (как долго?) Постоянно, непрестанно.

Из уст в уста - обстоятельство образа действия: (как? каким образом?) по цепочке, от человека к человеку, устно. Это обстоятельства разные по значению, и вопросы у них разные, значит они не однородны, но давайте возьмём следующее предложение:

> Созданная талантливым человеком песня… передавалась из уст в уста, из
> поколения в поколение. (Вс. Рождественский.)

Здесь явная однородность - "по цепочке". А теперь обратимся к нашему примеру. А ведь там ***из года в год*** тоже имеет оттенок смысла "**по цепочке**": от одного времени переходит к другому. А с другой стороны, в обоих фразеологизмах присутствует значение неизменности. Получается, что налицо ассимиляция и запятая действительно "напрашивается", чтобы усилить эту самую неизменность в идее высказывания. По-моему, здесь фигура речи - структурный параллелизм "из...в...", именно повтор структурных элементов и создаёт однородность, даже градацию, которую можно продолжить: из века в век, из года в год, из поколения в поколение, из уст в уста - одно и то же передаётся.

Answer (score 2):

*Как не изменить того, что передавалось **из года в год, из уст в уста**?*

Как всё сложно, даже про ассимиляцию вспомнили.

1. Начнем с того,что прочитать это предложение **без перечислительной интонации** довольно затруднительно, поэтому запятую надо ставить.
2. Это **однородные обстоятельства, сближенные по значению**. Общая тема — это способ передачи устной информации (из уст в уста), которая должна осуществляться непрерывно (из года в год), иначе информационный поток прервется.
3. Точно также **сближаются** по значению однородные определения, обозначающие **разные** признаки: *С бледным, покривившимся лицом он вдруг вскочил и схватил себя за голову* (пример из правил Розенталя).